# Is it appropriate to compare sample data to national data?

Tags: experiment-design, survey

For a research project I am doing, there is disagreement between my advisers as to whether it is appropriate to compare national data to our sample data. We will be using a national health survey, validated in several populations but necessarily in ours. We wanted to be able to compare the means from the national data to the data we will collect in order to examine if there is differences in our specific patient population. Is this generally accepted as good practice or is there other factors we need to consider before we directly compare this data?

Comment: Do you have the raw data from the national health study? If not, what statistics do you have (mean, standard deviation, number of observations)? Do you apply a treatment to your population?